# Is it possible to add a strong external password to iptables on port 22?

Tags: ssh, networking, security, iptables, firewall

I assume the answer to this question is "no", but I would imagine there is some alternative method of achieving this.

What I want to do is add a second, even stronger password, for when I login with ssh externally. (From outside my private network.)

Is it possible to do this?

I envision something like this; some kind of option in iptables which requires the user to enter a password in order to forward traffic from an external source via port 22. I'm not aware of any such feature in iptables for example, and I assume it is not possible since iptables makes routing decisions based on the headers of ip packets, whereas ssh information is contained inside an encrypted data payload inside the ip/tcp header(s).

Presumably something like this is used in enterprise grade equipment and organizations?

What about dual factor authentication, is something like that possible as an alternative?

Sorry for the slightly vague/unfocused question, I'm by no means experienced in this area.

Comment: This sounds a bit similar to my question on [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/154076/82570).

Comment: I do never allow SSH services for the Internet at large ; only via VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practise: Use key-based authentication, disable password-based authentication.

The best password-way to secure your SSH daemon is to disable password authentication altogether and force the use of key-based authentication.

This is considered more secure by a large factor and there is no more securing by password necessary.

Of course, do create keys and try logging in by keys before disabling password-based logins!

Documentation: [SSH.com: key-based authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/) [Digital Ocean: ssh key-based auth](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)

General SSH hardening tips: [Cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-openssh-server-best-practices.html) [Jason Rigden (includes 2FA)](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/hardening-ssh-1bcb99cd4cef) [Security Trails](https://securitytrails.com/blog/mitigating-ssh-based-attacks-top-15-best-security-practices)

Comment: Ok that's very interesting - this only applys to ssh but valuable information. Why is password authentication considered weak? Is this because keys are so large compared to passwords? Additionally, do I have to tempoarily allow passwords in order to move keys from one place to another?

Comment: The defining characteristic of a good password is entropy, see e.g. https://xkcd.com/936.  The entropy of a 4096 bit random ssh key is 4096 bit, a standard 8-character truly random password has around 48 bit (printable characters only as in Base64). Each additional bit doubles the number of necessary attempts by a brute force attacker (who tries out a list of passwords, or all possible values of a key).  As a result, a standard attacker will not even start to try out possible values of an ssh key.

Comment: Of course, the information about entropy does apply to other password scenarios. Too bad many do not offer key-based authentication. Oh, and by the way, in an ssh scenario the key is never transferred over the network so it cannot be stolen by an attacker listening (by breaking ssh connection encryption which is also hard). So: key => no plaintext password even over an encrypted line.